# Retrieving the local IP address based on HttpConnection using Java

Tags: java, network-programming

Is there any way to determine the IP address of the socket used to create the HTTP connection when the class used to create the connection was HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: Is it local IP or the IP of machine where the URL points to?

Comment: I'm looking for the local IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, the HttpURLConnection is an abstract class. The actual connection is implemented in code provided by the JRE. As such, there are no methods that will give you access to the actual Socket used.